# Eliminar dato segun fecha de vencimiento

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un sistema en donde hay productos de alimento que tienen vencimiento de 7 dias a 4 años o ilimitado que eso depende de un tema interno.

La base de datos de prueba es asi

```
id(int) producto(varchar)   valor(varchar)  fechap(date)    fechal(int)
1       Pan Lactal          150             2020-02-01      15
2       Harina              75              2020-02-11      30
3       Aceite              150             2020-02-28      15
4       Fideos              80              2020-03-01      30
```

vencimientoAutomatico.php

```
<?php
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<a href="altaVencimientoA.php">Agregar</a>
<?php
$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM pruebados ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = $list->fetch()) {
?>
<p>
<?=$row['producto'];?> - $<?=$row['valor'];?><br>
Ingresado el <?=$row['fechap'];?><br>
Vence en <?=$row['fechal'];?> dias
</p>

<?php
if($row['fechap'] == $row['fechal']){

  $sql = "DELETE FROM pruebados WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);                                   
  $stmt->execute();

}
}
?>
```

En `altaVencimientoA.php` hice un condicional para poder elimiar el producto vencido. Pense en un momento solo modificar un valor `0` para activo y `1` para inactivo, pero no se si eso estaria bien entonces preferi que se elimine.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<p>Nuevo Producto</p>
<?php

$hoy = date('Y-m-d');

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
if(!empty($_POST['producto']) && !empty($_POST['valor'])) {
$add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pruebados (producto, valor, fechap, fechal) VALUES (:producto, :valor, :fechap, :fechal)");
$add->bindValue(':producto', $_POST['producto']);
$add->bindValue(':valor', $_POST['valor']);
$add->bindValue(':fechap', $hoy);
$add->bindValue(':fechal', $_POST['fvence']);
$add->execute();
header('location: vencimientoAutomatico.php');
}
else {
echo '<div class="cmpl">Error</div>';
}
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<p><input type="text" name="producto" placeholder="Producto"></p>

<p><input type="text" name="valor" placeholder="Valor"></p>

<p>
<select name="fvence">
<option>Vence en...</option>
<option value="7">Una semana</option>
<option value="15">Dos semanas</option>
<option value="30">Un mes</option>
<option value="180">Sies meses</option>
<option value="365">Un a&ntilde;o</option>
<option value="1460">Ilimiatado</option> <!-- 1825 dias equivalen a 4 años -->
</select>
</p>

<p><button name="add">Add</button></p>
</form>
```

El problema es que no se elimina el producto vencido, como pasa con el `Pan Lactal` que fue publicado el 01/02/2020 y vencia en 15 dias. No se como puedo solucionar, el condicional lo eliminaria, pero no funciona.

Espero me ayuden.
Muy agradecida.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto se podría resolver también a nivel de la base de datos. Desde la versión `5.1.6` de MySQL se introdujeron los eventos programados.

Significa que puedes programar eventos que se lancen en un intervalo temporal (cada `N` días, semanas, meses, años, horas, minutos, segundos).

Para tu caso podrías entonces crear un evento en la base de datos y a disfrutar. La base de datos hará el trabajo en lo adelante sin necesidad de nada más. Con la ventaja añadida de que no tendrás que programar un cron para que ejecute el código PHP que después de taaanto sacrificio habrás creado. Y sin correr el riesgo de que te hagan inyección de código malicioso<sup>1</sup>.

Te pongo dos ejemplos, uno para borrar las filas que estén expiradas y otro para actualizarlas en caso de que quieras guardar una referencia a ellas. También, si quiseras, puedes programar algo más completo, que traslade los registros expirados a una tabla histórica por ejemplo, pero no sé si eso te interesa y, en cualquier caso, ya eso se aleja del propósito de tu pregunta.

Aquí vamos:

### Evento que borra los expirados

```
CREATE EVENT delete_expires
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
    DELETE FROM pruebados WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),fechap) >= fechal;
```

Creo que se entiende bien: `EVERY 1 DAY` le indica que se ejecute ese evento cada un día. Y en la consulta usamos `DATEDIFF` para verificar si el total de días entre la fecha actual y `fechap` es mayor o igual a `fechal`.

### Evento que actualiza una columna para indicar los expirados

```
CREATE EVENT update_expires
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
    UPDATE pruebados SET expired=true WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),fechap) >= fechal;
```

Aquí he supuesto una columna `expired` definida `boolean DEFAULT false` y el evento la establecerá a `true` si se cumple la condición del `WHERE`.

*That's all folks!*

### Enlaces sobre los eventos

1. [Introducción a los eventos (Manual de Referencia de MySQL)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html)
2. [Explicaciones más detalladas sobre los ejemplos con ejemplos (Manual de Referencia de MySQL)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html)
3. [Tutorial sobre los eventos](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

---

### Notas

1. Lo digo por tu consulta `$sql = "DELETE FROM pruebados WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'";` en la cual renuncias a las buenas prácticas aplicadas en las anteriores consultas. Deberías implementar también con respecto a ella consultas preparadas para mitigar el riesgo de *inyección SQL*.

Comment: Gracias Cedano, voy a buscar consultas preparadas no sabia de las inyecciones SQL

Answer (score 4):

Teniendo en cuenta esta condición,

```
if($row['fechap'] == $row['fechal']){
  $sql = "DELETE FROM pruebados WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);                                   
  $stmt->execute();

}
```

y estos datos:

```
id  producto    valor   fechap      fechal
1   Pan Lactal  150     01/02/2020  15
2   Harina      75      01/03/2020  30
3   Aceite      150     01-03-2020  15
4   Fideos      80      01-03-2020  30
```

Estás comparando si "01/02/2020" == "15" y siempre te dará que es falso, por eso no se eliminan los productos.

Una solución relativamente sencilla es ver la diferencia de días entre la fechap y NOW() que es la fecha y hora actual del tu servidor de base de datos. Una vez tengamos la cantidad se puede validar si realmente han pasado N días para proceder con la eliminación.

Sin tener ningún ciclo con esta sentencia debería servirte:

```
  $sql = "DELETE FROM pruebados WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(fechap, NOW())) > fechal";
```

Esta pequeña sentencia de sql borrará todos los registros que cumplan la condición SÍ SÓLO SÍ la diferencia de dias entre la fecha del producto y la fecha actual es mayor a los días de vencimiento se deberá borrar.

Comment: Que tonta que soy, estoy probando fuera del `while` asi: `$sql = "DELETE FROM pruebados WHERE DATEDIFF(fechap, NOW()) > fechal";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);                                 
$stmt->execute();` y no funciona

Comment: Estoy detallando como guardas la fecha y debes tener cuidado, @AntoniaHerrera estás guardando formatos diferentes como    01/03/2020  ó 01-03-2020, debes tenerlo en formato DATETIME O DATE para que DATEDIFF te funcione corrrectamente.

Comment: esta pensando en eso, lo estoy guardando asi `$hoy = date('d-m-Y');` pero y si tiene que estar en formato americano? que creo que es `$hoy = date('Y-m-d');` creo

Comment: Sería $hoy = date('Y-m-d'); y en mysql tipo de dato: DATE

Comment: Ya lo cambie porque estaba como VARCHAR tanto `fechap` como `fechal` (fecha limite que son los dias) y no funciona

Comment: Fechal lo tienes de tipo entero porque serían los días que expiran, ese debería ser un entero.

Comment: Hice el cambio y tampoco funciona

Comment: Recuerda revisar los datos de fechal y mirar si efectivamente ahora es entero.

Comment: Si, la cantidad de dias a vencer `fechal` es un int(6)` en la base de datos

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarme los datos de tu tabla para validar?

Comment: Edite la base de datos arriba tal cual esta de manera local

Comment: id 1 y id 2 están con este formato: '01/02/2020', debería ser: '01-02-2020 '

Comment: Ya esta actualizada la base de datos y ya edite como se ve la fecha ahora

Comment: $sql = "DELETE FROM pruebados WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(fechap, NOW())) > fechal";

Comment: Ahi funciono, gracias, pero te puedo pedir que me expliques que hiciste y porque usas DATEDIFF y ABS? porque estoy mareada y no entiendo nada, gracias!

Comment: DATEDIFF halla los días que hay entre dos fechas... Si cambias los parámetros de DATEDIFF (NOW(), fechap) tendrás el resultado positivo, como lo dejamos al revés tenemos días negativos porque busca entre la fecha del producto que es vieja y la actual. Por ello abs soluciona el inconveniente, tambien se puede arreglar dejando la condición con <> o cambiando el sentido como mencioné arriba.