# Como pasar tablas de una base de datos a otra con diferente conexion

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando copiar x tablas de una base de datos a otra con diferentes conexiones, he encontrado como hacerlo para la misma conexión pero si es diferente no encuentro nada. Alguien me podria decir como plantearlo.

```
$Connection = ConnectionManager :: get ('default2');

    $resultado = $Connection->execute('SELECT * FROM ROL')->fetchAll('assoc');

    $Connection = ConnectionManager :: get ('default');

    $Connection->execute('DELETE FROM roles');

    foreach ($resultado as $row)
    {
        $Connection->execute('INSERT INTO roles (id, descripcion) VALUES ('.$row['ROL_COD'].', "'.$row['ROL_NOM'].'")');
    }
```

Mi idea seria hacer eso por cada tabla pero no creo que sea lo más optimo y no se como meter estro dentro de una transiccion por si falla alguna.
Esto lo hace bien obtengo los valor de mi tabla sql ROL y los inserto en mi tabla mysql roles, pero esto lo deberia hacer para x tablas

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitas es hacer una migración puntual, es decir, algo que vas a hacer una sola vez  o es una funcionalidad que quieres implementar con PHP en tu aplicación?

Comment: es una funcionalidad que quiero implementar para coger informacion de unas tablas cada x tiempo

Comment: Lo fundamental es que: **el usuario con el que te conectes tenga privilegios en ambas bases de datos**. Con ese requisito, podrías hacer una consulta de este tipo: `INSERT INTO dbDestino.tablaDestino SELECT * FROM dbOrigen.tablaOrigen` por la notación usada sabrás a qué corresponde cada cosa. No está de más decir que ambas tablas deberían tener idéntica estructura. Si estamos hablando de tablas con muchos datos, convendría que lo hicieras directamente por consola, no desde PHP. Y, si es algo para hacer cada X tiempo, piensa en programar un Cron (`ssh`) o un `TRIGGER` (Base de Datos)
`

Comment: Si esa idea la vi pero eso son para bases de datos con una misma conexion entiendo, mi ideas es programar un cron

Comment: Lo mejor para este tipo de cosas es hacerlo al más bajo nivel posible. O sea, si puedes hacerlo directamente en consola mucho mejor, sin tener que pasar por PHP, lo cual supondría agregar una capa más, más lentitud y más riesgo de algún fallo, sobre todo si es una operación que podría ser costosa debido a una eventual tabla muy grande por ejemplo. Ahora bien, si tienes que pasar por PHP, no sé si mysqli o PDO permiten consultar entre distintas BD (no lo he probado). De no poderse, tendrías que hacer dos conexiones, traer los datos y luego insertarlos en la otra tabla...

Comment: ... en ese caso deberías usar transacciones, para controlar posibles fallos. De todos modos, yo usaría PHP si no me quedará otra opción. Es mejor consola directamente, o programar un `TRIGGER` en la misma base de datos. Desde una determinada versión (si mal no recuerdo) MySQL permite programar `TRIGGER` que se disparan cada X tiempo, exactamente como fiuncionan los Cron.

Comment: Puntualizo algo sobre mis comentarios anteriores, no son `TRIGGER` en sí, sino **eventos programados**, [+ info aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333680/29967). Allí están también los enlaces al MR de MySQL.

Comment: Si es para cojer toda la información de una BBDD a otra BBDD, cada x tiempo, quizás podrías usar un script de migración y un cron. Esto se haría en background y no ocuparía "tiempo" en tu aplicación PHP.