# Tabla Mysql y/o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Quiero mostrar por web, una tabla de Mysql que simule mostrar datos en tiempo real.

Quisiera saber si es posible hacer una tabla en Mysql con datos que puedan cambiar cada cierto tiempo, es decir, si tengo una columna con 6 datos numéricos, que estos cambien y/o varien entre [-5 y 5], cada 2-3 segundos.

De ser posible, ¿cómo debe hacerse?

Sino, ¿cómo podría hacerse desde PHP?

Comment: asi como esta la pregunta, la respuesta es si a todo... y basada en opiniones.. tal vez, si explicas un poco mas, podemos darte una respuesta mas clara...

Comment: Si, quisiera formular mejor la pregunta, pero no logro hacerlo; quiero mostrar por una web, una tabla con datos que varíen o "cambien", y que simulen ser datos mostrados en tiempo real.

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y ahi podes agregar toda la informacion que desess en la pregunta.. vas a tener que crear un cron en la base de datos que simule eso...

Comment: A partir de la versión 5.1.6 de MySQL puedes programar eventos en la base de datos. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333680/29967).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes generar los elementos desde PHP, con los valores obtenidos de la base de datos y comenzar a simular actualizaciones con javascript usando [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random)

```js
// Define la variable que contendrá los input
let datos;

// Crea una función para actualizar
const updateData = function() {
    // Recorre y asigna un valor al azar entre -5 y 5
    datos.forEach(item => {
        // Obtener número entre 1 y 5
        let newVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1) + 1);
        // Asignar signo al azar
        item.value = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? -newVal : newVal;
    });
    // Volver a ejecutar dentro de 3 segundos (3000 milisegundos)
    setTimeout(updateData, 3000);
}

// Cargar los datos y ejecutar función cuando el DOM se haya cargado
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    datos = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=dato]');
    updateData();
});
```

```html
<div>
    Dato 1:
    <input type="number" id="dato1">
</div>
<div>
    Dato 2:
    <input type="number" id="dato2">
</div>
<div>
    Dato 3:
    <input type="number" id="dato3">
</div>
<div>
    Dato 4:
    <input type="number" id="dato4">
</div>
<div>
    Dato 5:
    <input type="number" id="dato5">
</div>
<div>
    Dato 6:
    <input type="number" id="dato6">
</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, esta buenisima la respuesta. Un punto, como tendría que hacerlo para que esta misma función aleatoria, funcionara en una tabla o columna de una base de datos, llamada y mostrada por php?

Comment: Tendrías que ejecutar una llamada AJAX crear el valor para cada campo en PHP, usando [random_int()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.random-int.php), actualizar en MySQL y devolverlos, de preferencia, en formato JSON.

Comment: Creo que me pierdo mucho con eso... podrias darme un ejemplo mas grafico?

Comment: Si no sabes AJAX, comienza por aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Comment: Se lo basico, como hacer la llamada para mostrar la tabla, pero no logro "tomar" la columna, y luego seleccionar los datos para que estos varien como deseo.

Comment: Crea una nueva pregunta sobre "MySQL: Cómo actualizar columnas con valor al azar" y no olvides poner todos los datos: Conexión, estructura de tablas y todo lo necesario para que podamos hacer pruebas y tratar de responder.

Comment: Ya esta hecha, espero puedan ayudarme, saludos.