# calcular los días trancurridos con java y guardar en mysql

Tags: java, mysql

[![  public void calculardias(JDateChooser fechainicio, JDateChooser fechafin){
if (fechainicio.getDate()!=null && fechafin.getDate()!=null) {
Calendar inicio = fechainicio.getCalendar();
Calendar fin = fechafin.getCalendar();
int dias = -1;

```
            while(inicio.before(fin) || inicio.equals(fin)){
                dias++;
                inicio.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);   
            }  
            if (dias<=365) {
            txtresultado.setText("Los dias trancurridos son:" + dias);
           
        }else{
              txtresultado.setText("Es mayor de 365");   
              
            }
                
            
    }else{
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hay campos vacios, debe llenar todos los datos");
    }
}][1]][1]
```

buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código para calcular los días transcurridos en java pero necesito guardarlo en una base de datos y que se actualice cada día en la base y se pueda visualizar en un jtable en java

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no programas un evento en la base de datos? Si te interesa explorar esa posibilidad [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333680/29967) tienes más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar la funcion TIMESTAMPDIFF de Mysql y asi obtener la diferencia de dias entre la fecha de inicio y la fecha actual del sistema. De esta forma no necesitas estar actualizando el campo de la base de datos.
Luego este valor lo agregas al array List de la consulta y lo muestras en el jtable

El codigo mysql es el siguiente:

```
select  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, inicio, (select sysdate()) ) as diasTranscurridos  from tabla
```

inicio y tabla hacen referencia a tu campo de la base de datos y a la tabla.
Si deseas mostrar mas información como las horas y minutos transcurridos puedes usar la siguiente consulta concatenada

```
select concat( TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, inicio, (select sysdate())), ' dias, ', MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, inicio, (select sysdate())), 24), ' horas y ', 
MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, inicio, (select sysdate())), 60), ' minutos ') as tiempoTranscurrido  from  tabla
```

Aqui te dejo una imagen de como se visualizaría la diferencia de dias,horas y minutos en el jtable. La Fecha y hora  representan el momento en en cual se hizo el registro en la base de datos,  tiempo transcurrido hace referencia a la diferencia que hay con la fecha actual del sistema (cuando hice la captura de pantalla claro)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]