# Duda sobre triggers i delete programados

Tags: sql, mysqli

Quería preguntar si se puede programar algún tipo de función en sql utilizando triggers , para que en cierta hora , diariamente se podría borrar los registros de base de datos , pro ejemplo para cambiar el menú diario de restaurante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día,  se que se pueden hacer tareas definidas en una base de datos, pero la realidad es que no tengo idea de como, yo solo he utilizado triggers pero en tiempo de ejecución y es un tanto diferente a lo que tu necesitas, bueno busque de rápido y encontré este tema que podría serte útil https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2008/07/11/triggersql/  ahi hablan de este tema y puede que encuentres el mecanismo adecuado.  Saludos

Comment: yo creo que será mas bien algo como esto, http://juancarlosmolinos.net/bases-de-datos/mysql/ddl-y-dml/jobs-en-mysql/, por que un trigger, solo se ejecuta en el momento que se realiza la consulta, y un job debe ser automático, que lo lance

Comment: Desde la versión 5.1.6 MySQL incorporó **eventos programados** que sirven para lanzar código en un tiempo determinado. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333680/29967). Allí se explica un poco en qué consiste, hay un código de ejemplo y al final tienes los enlaces de la doc.