# Actualizar llaves foraneas de MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hola que tal? Necesito un código que actualice las llaves foráneas de bases de datos, por tanto tengo que leer las que hay y de esta forma agregarlas  o en algun caso modificar las llaves foráneas.
Para poder realizar esto yo guardo la estructura de la base de datos a la que quiero que se mantenga
guardando la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT i.TABLE_NAME, i.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, i.CONSTRAINT_NAME, k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i 
LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k ON i.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
WHERE i.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
AND i.TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
```

Al guardar toda la información recibida la guardo en un archivo y luego las comparo realizando el mismo Query (El anterior) y al verificar que hay una diferencia utilizo las siguientes herramientas.

```
ALTER TABLE tabla1 
ADD CONSTRAINT nombreclaveforanea 
FOREIGN KEY (campotabla1) 
REFERENCES tablaquereferencia (campoquereferencia) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
```

El problema que se me presenta es el ON delete "la accion al borrar la llave a la que hace referencia y cuando se actualiza tambien... el problema es que no la encuentro en INFORMATION_SCHEMA, alguien me podria decir o sabe donde se encuentra toda la informacion de la llave foranea y de que manera puedo acceder a ella con el fin de comparar dos bases de datos?

Comment: No entendí del todo lo que intentas hacer, pero me pregunto: ¿no puedes resolver esto definiendo restricciones de [*integridad referencial*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), o mediante [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) o mediante [`EVENT`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333680/29967). Son procesos automáticos que una vez configurados se encargan de mantener tus tablas sin necesidad de intervención manual, evitando el riesgo que eso supone.

Comment: ¡Yo hago modificaciones constantemente en la base de datos para realizar pruebas, por tanto, cuando necesito realizar una actualización tengo que realizar esta mediante un procedure, donde agregue las llaves foráneas donde no las allá, para actualizar!