# ¿Cómo borrar un registro de una base de datos con php y mysql después de un tiempo?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una serie de registros en una tabla para mostrar en mi pagina web, quiero que los registros desaparezcan de mi pagina web después de un tiempo, ¿Cómo le puedo hacer con php y mysql? He oído del programador de eventos en mysql pero no se como se implementaría y quisiera una forma mas sencilla si es que la hay. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: En la tabla, tienen que haber registros de cuándo se inserta la consulta, al cargar la página, te conectas a la base de datos con PHP, usa [date_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-diff.php) para obtener la diferencia entre ambas fechas, y elimina el registro cuando haiga pasado un tiempo que creas considerable

Comment: Además, puedo explicarte esto paso a paso detalladamente, pero ¿Qué has intentado específicamente?

Comment: tiene razon @anythingg y dependiendo para que lo desees es que puedes implementar 2 opciones:
1. cada vez que naveguen por tu web el sistema consulte los registros con una fecha menor a la que tu establescas o puedes usar la fecha actual y restarle la cantidad de dias que quieras (lento)
2. un espacio espcifico (mantenimiento.php) donde accedes cuando tu quieras limpiar tus registros y hace lo de la opcion 1 .

Comment: La forma más sencilla precisamente es el programador de eventos del mismo SGBD. Programas el evento allí y listo. Si lo haces desde PHP es más complicado, porque primero tienes que crear el script y luego buscar la forma de lanzarlo periódicamente usando un Cron o de otro modo. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333680/29967) hay un ejemplo para crear eventos desde MySQL.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas, me han servido mucho, ya lo puedo hacer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera más facil y simple, sería utilizando los eventos de MySql. Ahí puedes gatillar un query a tal hora o cada cierto tiempo: ejemplo:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS test_event_01
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2020-10-10 01:00:00'
DO
  DELETE FROM TU_TABLA WHERE ......;
```

Nota: **EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2020-10-10 01:00:00'**:  Sinifica que el evento se gatilla todos los inicios de semana empezando desde la fecha: 2020-10-10 01:00:00.

Guia Oficial:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-overview.html

Una Guía adicional
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/